# Package contains directories which cannot be renamed

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to get my app ready for alpha testing and am struggling to rename my project packages - as it would appear that com.android is a restricted package name - however when following the instructions outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package?noredirect=1&lq=1) I get the following message:[image] - I'm...not sure what to do here as this window differs from what is given in the instructions. Has anyone encountered this and is able to help me?

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Did you get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the trick/method for changing project package name after wasting $12 on the fiverr. This method works for me in Android Studio 4.0.

You just need to change this line only in `build.gradle(app level).`

```
applicationId "codetrix.cleaner"
```

Just change the text in " " quotes. Your new package will be your updated text.

Comment: awesome! it's been a while since I've looked over this but I'll go ahead and mark this as the answer hoping it helps others

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change your package name, please follow below steps:

1. Change your package name in AndroidManifest.xml:
   package="your_new_package_name"
2. Rebuild project, you have to fix many import of R file.
3. Change the package name of java by Right click -> Refactor -> Rename on the package. This is an optional step, #1 and #2 should change your package name already.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't help as I still seem to be getting compilation errors (unrelated to this) - I think I'll just go the nuclear option and make an entirely new project and copy everything over line by line - save myself the headache.

I appreciate the help though.

Comment: yes, it is a brute-force way, slow but definitely success.

Comment: Hey, I am facing same problem, did you get it?

Comment: @TariqMahmood unfortunately I did not! I ended up just remaking the project entirely and recopying everything - it's a bit extreme but it did fix it.